# I have a list of values per item, and a separate list of items per category. How can I return the totals for each category, with a formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to do a SUMIF formula for each "Category" name, but the data I'm trying to sum are all "Items" in the category. I know there are ways to do this with VBA, but how can I do this with a formula?

For a simple example, I created 3 simple tables:

Sales per Item (A1:B7)

Item per Category (D1:E7)

I want to know Sales per Category (G1:H3)

Since I don't have the "reputation" yet to post images, here is a link to a screenshot:

[image: 1]

https://imgur.com/IpLXuYF][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qPWM.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qPWM.png)

Obviously, a simple SUMIF only works if I go through the time of creating a new Category column in the first table. For reasons I won't go into, this is unscalable.

I have also tried using a TEXTJOIN within a SUMIF to create an array of matching items for each category, but am only returning 0s.

The following code (entered into H2) returns the list of items per category (note that the outer braces are from using Control-Shift-Enter, to make it an array formula):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(D2:D7=G2,E2:E7,""))}
```

But if I nest that inside a SUMIF, like so:

```
{=SUMIF(A2:A7,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(D2:D7=G2,E2:E7,"")),B2:B7)}
```

it returns 0, because it's treating the TEXTJOIN value as a single string, rather than as an array.

I have not found a way for it to treat the TEXTJOIN as multiple criteria. Or any other solution to my problem, for that matter.

I would love to find a formula that solves this problem, as it would help in many other applications, as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,IF($D$2:$D$7=G2,$E$2:$E$7)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Perfect! I did not think to SUM the SUMIFS! Thank you for your quick response!